# There's a white blur on my cover image of my website in mobile mode. How can i remove it?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

Whenever this website (https://scavengerwoodworks.com/) goes into mobile mode, the overlay on top of the cover image turns white making the words illegible. Is there anyway i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: In your customizer CSS write code:

```
.opacity-full.bg-white.display-none.xs-display-block {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Option 2: remove the bg-white class from your home page in the code below.

```
<div class="opacity-full bg-white display-none xs-display-block"></div>
```

Option 3: Comment out line 280 of your styles.css does the trick but will affect the style wherever it is applied to your website.

```
/* ===================================
    Background color
====================================== */
.bg-white{/* background: #fff */}
```